# Adjust the right side of the image to make it responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive image using HTML and CSS. What I am trying to achieve is, as the screen size reduces, the right side of the image to crop to maintain the height and position of the image. A reference to this is how nikes hero image is.The reason for this style is-just like on the nike website I have white space to the left and right side of my image. I want to preserve the white space when the screen is being resized.How do I achieve this? I am attaching part of my code below

```css
.hero {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 6.7rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.hero>img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1330px;
  height: 690px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <img src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/q_auto:eco/t_product_v1/f_auto/dpr_2.0/w_441,c_limit/9d1635ed-eed0-45b0-b34d-e00468e2f79e/tanjun-easyon-shoes-mplG1H.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: you may just try `max-width:100%; max-height:100%;` if I understand correctly

Comment: _"A reference to this is how nikes hero image is."_ - that is as vague as possibly could be. Even if we were all talking about the same site here, it might still change at some point in the future. So please do not use vague references like this in your problem descriptions. Use your own words to explain the issue/situation.

Comment: Hey @CBroe, the syntax for the hero image i.e., the first image you see when you land on Nike website is the same across time and location. But thanks for the feedback

Comment: hey @DiegoD, I cannot use max-height as 100% because it adjusts the height to fit the screen. I want the height to stay the same. I want the width/image to reduce/crop to maintain the height while still maintaining the white space that is to the left and right of the image.

Comment: _"i.e., the first image you see when you land on Nike website"_ - that _this_ - referring to an external site - is not the correct way to explain the situation, is what I was trying to tell you to begin with here.

Comment: hey @CBroe, maybe I didn't make myself clear. The reason I mentioned a reference is that I thought it made my position clear to understand. And when I say the first image you see on the Nike website- Nike changes its hero image regularly but the CSS of the image and its responsiveness are the same across the time and location. But I get your point so thanks again for the feedback

Comment: _"The reason I mentioned a reference is that I thought it made my position clear to understand"_ - but it _doesn't_ do that, if you don't mention what _specific_ site you are referring to in the first place; and it _won't_ do this for future readers of this question, if the content of that site ever _changes_ in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I wanted with the following CSS code. Thanks for the help everyone

```css
.hero {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 6.7rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.hero>img {
    width:90%; /* Occupy the full width of the container */
    max-width: 1330px; /* Ensure the image doesn't exceed its natural dimensions */
    height: 690px;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, we can add some property in css and the HTML code nothing has been fixed.

```css
        .hero {
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            width: 70vw;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .hero>img {
            width: 70vw;
            object-fit: cover;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <img src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/q_auto:eco/t_product_v1/f_auto/dpr_2.0/w_441,c_limit/9d1635ed-eed0-45b0-b34d-e00468e2f79e/tanjun-easyon-shoes-mplG1H.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To create a responsive image that maintains its height and crops the right side as the screen size reduces, you can use CSS and the object-fit property, similar to what you've started with. However, you also need to adjust the container's size to maintain the desired aspect ratio.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this effect:

```css
.hero {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1330px; /* Set your desired max width */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container horizontally */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflowing content */
 }

.hero img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* Let the image determine its own height */
  object-fit: cover; /* Crop the image to cover the container */
 }
```

```html
<div class="hero">
       <img src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/q_auto:eco/t_product_v1/f_auto/dpr_2.0/w_441,c_limit/9d1635ed-eed0-45b0-b34d-e00468e2f79e/tanjun-easyon-shoes-mplG1H.png" alt="">
     </div>
```